# How to use windows DLLs in python, specifically windows.graphics.dll?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, graphics

To be honest, I only know that a dll is a windows library and that I can use `win32api.LoadLibrary` to load them, but I'm not sure how to use them with this command. Or even the syntax that I would use with it. I'm making a graphics library with python and `windows.graphics.dll` seemed like a good place to start. I'm just getting into this kind of stuff in python and I'm probably doing thisa bit early, but I still would like to try this.

Comment: I think you should look into the ctypes module which can be used to load DLLs.

Comment: @afc11hn Yes, I am familiar with that, but I don't know how I would use it for this DLL or what syntax I need for it to work properly